# Eventbrite API: is there a way to access the waitlist?

Tags: eventbrite

We use EventBrite for managing some free events: works great.

We also make extensive use of the waitlist feature.

I would like to script the synchronisation of the EventBrite ticket list contacts (sold and waitlist) with another system.

(yes, I know, I can manage contacts in EventBrite. But we have an existing system and I want to keep using that)

There does not appear to be an obvious way to retrieve any information about people on the waitlist via the API? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the available API access methods are listed here: 
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods

Waitlists are not currently available.

Comment: In a related question, is there a way to suggest features to EventBrite to add to their API? 'cos this seems like it would be easy to do, and useful.

Comment: I would try sending suggestions/recommendations to api@eventbrite.com.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Run it in your web browser to see an xml list of all attendees:

https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_list_attendees?id=123456&app_key=your_app_key

You'll have to signup for a developer's key to run the query though: https://www.eventbrite.com/api/key/

The down and dirty method to get the eventID to make sure it's working is to view the page source of your EventBrite page, and search for "eventID" or "eid".

You can get the event id through the EventBrite API as well: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/

Comment: Good answer, but I think he was hoping for waitlist information (pending registrations) in addition to the list of attendees (completed registrations).  
Waitlist information is not currently available via their API.

Comment: I read right over the wait list requirement in the question (not sure how I missed that). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes, it was specifically the people on the waitlist I want to retrieve in addition to the ticket holders. I know I can retrieve the list of ticket holders ...